# Como importar un excel en javascript para usar sus datos?

Tags: javascript, excel

soy nuevo en programación con javascript y estoy programando una web donde me salgan preguntas  ( en formato a,b,c,d (tipo test)) en orden aleatorio , las preguntas las tengo en un excel y nose como importarlo. Estoy familiarizado con PANDAS De Python  y nose si se puede importar como el excel de alguna manera muy similar (en javascript para la web). Espero que se entienda mi pregunta, si tienen alguna duda comentarlo. Cuelgo el javascript y el excel.

**Lo que hice es escribir las preguntas a mano, pero como son muchas y las tengo en un excel es mucha tarea**
*es mi primera pregunta por stack overflow, me tengo que acostumbrar al formato :)*

```
var Preguntas=new Array()
Preguntas[0]=["JUNY 2021","En una economía, la población activa es de 5 millones de personas y la tasa de paro es del 10%. Supongamos que la economía recibe 2 millones de inmigrantes, de los cuales la mitad busca empleo. De los que buscan empleo, solo 900.000 lo encuentran. (Se supone que todos los inmigrantes tienen los papeles en regla.) Después del aumento de la inmigración, la tasa de paro:","no", ,"No ha variado.","Aumentó.","Disminuyó.","No se puede calcular.","a",1]
Preguntas[1]=["JUNY 2021","Si tu reta (antes de pagar IRPF) aumenta de 10.000€/año a 15.000€/año y lo que tienes que pagar en concepto de IRPF aumenta de 2.000€ a 4.500€, el tipo impositivo marginal es del:","no", ,"20%","30%","45%","50%","d",1]
var Q = Preguntas.length;
var Aleatori = Math.round(Math.random()*(Q-1));


document.getElementById("idfrases").innerHTML = Preguntas[Aleatori][1];
document.getElementById("optA").innerHTML = "A. "+ Preguntas[Aleatori][4];
document.getElementById("optB").innerHTML = "B. "+Preguntas[Aleatori][5];
document.getElementById("optC").innerHTML = "C. "+Preguntas[Aleatori][6];
document.getElementById("optD").innerHTML = "D. "+Preguntas[Aleatori][7];

var errades = 0;
var correctes = 0;
document.getElementById("A").addEventListener("click", function(){resposta("a");});
document.getElementById("B").addEventListener("click", function(){resposta("b");});
document.getElementById("C").addEventListener("click", function(){resposta("c");});
document.getElementById("D").addEventListener("click", function(){resposta("d");});
document.getElementById("seguent").addEventListener("click", function(){passa()});




function resposta(res){
   if(res == Preguntas[Aleatori][8]) {
    document.getElementById("solucio").innerHTML = "¡Correcto!";
    document.getElementById("A").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("B").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("C").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("D").disabled = true;
    correctes++;
    Preguntas[Aleatori][9] = 2 
    document.getElementById("estanbe").innerHTML = "Correctas: "+correctes;
    document.getElementById("estanmalament").innerHTML = "Errores: "+errades;
}
else if(res != Preguntas[Aleatori][8]) {
    document.getElementById("solucio").innerHTML = "¡Nooo! LA SOLUCIÓ és la "+Preguntas[Aleatori][8];
    /*if(Preguntas[Aleatori][8]=="a"){

        document.getElementById("A").disabled = false;
    }*/

    document.getElementById("A").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("B").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("C").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("D").disabled = true;
    errades++;
    document.getElementById("estanbe").innerHTML = "Correctas: "+correctes;
    document.getElementById("estanmalament").innerHTML = "Errores: "+errades;
    }
}

function passa(){
   if(correctes == Q) acaba(); /**/
   else { /**/
    Aleatori = Math.round(Math.random()*(Q-1));
    if(Preguntas[Aleatori][9] == 2) passa2(); /**/
    else{ /**/
        document.getElementById("idfrases").innerHTML = Preguntas[Aleatori][1];
        document.getElementById("optA").innerHTML = "A. "+ Preguntas[Aleatori][4];
        document.getElementById("optB").innerHTML = "B. "+ Preguntas[Aleatori][5];
        document.getElementById("optC").innerHTML = "C. " + Preguntas[Aleatori][6];
        document.getElementById("optD").innerHTML = "D. " + Preguntas[Aleatori][7];
        document.getElementById("solucio").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("A").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("B").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("C").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("D").disabled = false;
    }
}
}

function passa2(){

   Aleatori++;
   if(Preguntas[Aleatori][9] == 2) passa2()
   else {
    document.getElementById("idfrases").innerHTML = Frases[Aleatori][1];
    document.getElementById("optA").innerHTML = "A "+ Preguntas[Aleatori][4];
    document.getElementById("optB").innerHTML = "B "+ Preguntas[Aleatori][5];
    document.getElementById("optC").innerHTML = "C "+ Preguntas[Aleatori][6];
    document.getElementById("optD").innerHTML = "D "+ Preguntas[Aleatori][7];
    document.getElementById("solucio").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("A").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("B").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("C").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("D").disabled = false;
}
}

function acaba(){
document.getElementById("idfrases").innerHTML = "¡Felicidades! ¡Has acertado todas las frases que había disponibles! Cada vez estás mas preparad@ para el examen.";
document.getElementById("seguent").innerHTML = "Acabado";
document.getElementById("seguent").disabled = true;
}
```

EL excel nose como colgarlo pero puedo subir una foto y como os podeis inventar valores, tendira una forma asi.
[foto excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Im5G.png)

MUCHAS GRACIAS POR SU TIEMPO

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas una libreria para formatear el Excel a un JSON asimilable y manejable por Javascript.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Basicamente la puedes implementar con CDN:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Subida de Excel con Javascript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.15.3/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h4>Subida de Excel con Javascript y conversion a JSON</h4>
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Converso de EXCEL a JSON</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <!-- Input type file to upload excel file -->
                <input type="file" id="fileUpload" accept=".xls,.xlsx" /><br />
                <button type="button" id="uploadExcel">Convert</button>

                <!-- Render parsed JSON data here -->
                <div style="margin-top:10px;">
                    <pre id="jsonData"></pre>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        var selectedFile;
        document
          .getElementById("fileUpload")
          .addEventListener("change", function(event) {
            selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
          });
        document
          .getElementById("uploadExcel")
          .addEventListener("click", function() {
            if (selectedFile) {
              var fileReader = new FileReader();
              fileReader.onload = function(event) {
                var data = event.target.result;
    
                var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                  type: "binary"
                });
                workbook.SheetNames.forEach(sheet => {
                  let rowObject = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(
                    workbook.Sheets[sheet]
                  );
                  let jsonObject = JSON.stringify(rowObject);
                  document.getElementById("jsonData").innerHTML = jsonObject;
                  console.log(jsonObject);
                });
              };
              fileReader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);
            }
          });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias Julio, una duda que tengo, donde tengo que poner el nombre del archivo que quiero pasar a json? Puede que sea un poco estupida la pregunta, si lo es me disculpo.

Comment: No entiendo tu duda? si le das al boton azul de ejecutar te renderiza la solucion... alli hay un input boton para subir el archivo. 

La variable 'rowObject' contiene el objeto json que contiene el Json de la data del excel.

Si la respuesta fue la correcta no olvides indicarla como correcta.

Comment: Tipo yo en mi web no quiero que haya un input boton. Sino el archivo con los datos que ya este y asi sea el mismo para todos. Perdón por gastar tiempo en mi. Te pongo en contexto con lo que quiero hacer: quiero hacer una web para ayudar a la gente de mi universidad a practicar ejercicios que he recogido yo y los tengo en el excel. Y con ese excel hacer el programa que haga lo de aleatorizar las preguntas,(ese programa ya lo tengo creado lo que no sabia como hacer era como cojer los datos del excel desde javascript). EL formato de JSON me ha gustado mucho pero no necesito el boton de import.