# Angular Manipular Dato

Tags: angular, excel

Estoy trabajando con apliación en Angular. El incoveniente que tengo es al intentar leer un archivo Excel, se me genera un error por el tipo de dato "file".
¿Cómo puedo acceder a la información que almacena file? Deseo acceder al objeto, para manipular la data. Agradecería sus comentarios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías poner el código como texto, [formateado](/help/formatting) por favor? Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas una libreria para formatear el Excel a un JSON asimilable y manejable por Javascript.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

en otra respuesta lo expuse con ejemplo en Js: [Como importar un excel en javascript para usar sus datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/531665/como-importar-un-excel-en-javascript-para-usar-sus-datos/531679#531679)

Con Angular lo que hago es crear un componente que recibe el archivo, lo formatea en columnas y transforma en JSON y me lo devuelve con un `@Output() datos = new EventEmitter<Object[]>()`

Para lograr esto requieres los siguientes metodos:

- **obtenerDatos(file)** = toma el file y lo formatea usando XLS
- **selectHoja(hojas: any[])** = Toma las hojas del .xls y escoge una para extraer la data
- **enviarDatos(hoja)** = Toma la hoja de interes y la pasea a un formato JSON, luego la emite para ser manejada por otro componente.

El Codigo seria:

```
 import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output, ViewChild, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
 import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-carga-excel',
 templateUrl: './carga-excel.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./carga-excel.component.scss']
 })

 export class CargaExcelComponent {
    @Output() datos = new EventEmitter<Object[]>();
    public workbook;

    constructor(){}
     
 
    obtenerDatos(file) {
      this.workbook = null;
      this.hojas = [];
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => {
      let data = (<any>e.target).result;
      this.workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
         type: 'binary'
      });

      this.workbook.SheetNames.forEach((function (sheetName) {
        this.hojas.push(sheetName);
      }).bind(this), this);
      this.selectHoja(this.hojas)
     };

      reader.onerror = function (ex) {
       //manejar error de carga aqui
      console.log(ex);
      };
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    };

    selectHoja(hojas: any[]){
     ///aqui debes crear un metodo para seleccionar una de las hojas del 
     archivo... un select, un modal...etc... y enviar la hoja al metodo de 
     enviarDatos()
        this.cargarDatos(click.data)
    }
 
   private enviarDatos(hoja){
      let XL_row_object = 
      XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(this.workbook.Sheets[hoja]);
      let json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
      // aqui parseamos a json
      const datos = JSON.parse(json_object);

     //aqui lo emitimos al @Output() para ser capturado por otro componente
     if(datos){
        this.datos.emit(datos);
        this.uploadObj.clearAll()
     }
   }

 }
```